# Python 2.7.3 is not installed in centos 5.8

Tags: linux

Python 2.7.3 installation in centos

```
Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
bsddb185           dl                 imageop         
sunaudiodev                                           
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.


Failed to build these modules:
_sqlite3           bz2
```

please provide the solution

Answer (score 0):

You should install some packages before running the Python configuration.

I would not worry about `bsddb185`, `dl`, `imageop` and 'sunaudiodev' as they are deprecated since 2.6, and you probably do not need them.

However `sqlite3` and `bz2` are often used by other packages and for those you need to install `libsqlite3-dev` resp. `libbz2-dev` and then rerun Python's configure and rebuild.